# Converting Big List of Questions in TeX into Single Question View

Tags: ipad-app, latex, iphone-app, flashcard

I have questions in this format in tex files

```
Systemic venous congestion caused by
\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
\item heart problems,
\item thrombosis of the portal vein,
\item la la la lorem
\end{enumerate}a
... 777 questions
Systemic venous congestion caused by
\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
\item heart problems,
\item thrombosis of the portal vein,
\item la la la lorem
\end{enumerate}
```

I would like to make a simple app that asks me these questions randomly one at a time and finally returns rate.
iPad and iPhone apps would be nice - probably HTML version is enough seen can be seen on the browser.
Very simple GUI is enough.

**Which software would you use for this?**

Comment: I doubt that you'll find something that handles everything from the LaTeX source to the prompting and scorekeeping. How much fiddling are you prepared to do to, say, convert that TeX source into a bunch of text or HTML files, that could be input to a flash card app?

Comment: @Gilles The conversion of TeX into HTML should be straightforward.

Comment: @Masi True, but you won't find a tool that does both the conversion AND the question asking. Maybe it is better to focus on the questioning and scorekeeping part, and take care of the conversion to the required format afterwards

Comment: I think you need to break this up so that the recommendation here is for a flash-card like program with the options you need and some sort of import, this figure out how to convert your tex data to the input format required. I doubt asking for a flash card program that understands tex is going to get you anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know about [Anki](http://ankisrs.net/)?

It asks questions randomly from sources in LaTeX format (you might want to [read more](http://ankisrs.net/docs/manual.html) on how it works), provides frequency-based feedback (questions you answer wrong are shown more often than others), and is very nice to use.

You might be interested both in [AnkiWeb](https://ankiweb.net/), which is free, the desktop version, which is the recommended starting point, and the [iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ankisrs/id373493387?mt=8) version, which costs some 25$. The Web version can be used in iOS, if that's too much money for you.

In addition, using the [LaTeX Note Importer](http://www2.math.uni-wuppertal.de/~zibrowiu/LatexNoteImporter/) extension for Anki will allow you to import a bulk of question formated this way:

> `% -*- coding-system:utf-8 -*- \documentclass[12pt]{article}
>   \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} \newenvironment{note}{\paragraph{NOTE:}}{}
>   \newenvironment{field}{\paragraph{field:}}{} \begin{document}
>   \begin{note}    \begin{field}
>          Is it true that \(1 + 1 = 0\)?     \end{field}    \begin{field}
>          Yes and no. The equation
>          \begin{equation*}
>                     1+1 = 0
>          \end{equation*}
>          holds only in characteristic two.    \end{field} \end{note} \end{document}`

To sum up, the app **can read LaTeX notes** to help you **learn them**, asses you a bit differently from what you described, and is avaible on **iOS**.

Comment: Anki's interface is not planned for the bulk import of cards into the deck and not particularly for LaTeX. Too much Wysiwyg -styles there for me. Difficult to get the final result efficiently.

Comment: You should be able to get through quickly by using [card templates](http://ankisrs.net/docs/manual.html#card-templates). I do agree you might lose some time setting it up, but [importing](http://ankisrs.net/docs/manual.html#importing) can be done in bulk and you should be able to parse your TeX note into compatible sc-sv. I just found [this](http://www2.math.uni-wuppertal.de/~zibrowiu/LatexNoteImporter/), I'm editing my answer to feature it.